# Number of true statements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

A sheet of paper has statements numbered from 1 to 100. For each $N$, $1\leq N \leq100$, Statement $N$ says, "Exactly $N$ of the statements in this sheet are false". Which statements are true?

I can't seem to figure out the answer as every statement seems to contradict rest of the others. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: start off with 1,2,3 etc - can it ever be overall consistent?

Comment: that's where I'm stuck. It isn't consistent overall and I'm unable to figure out which are the correct statements henceforth

Comment: Statement $99$ could be true.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in that each of the statements contradict one another. So at most one of the statements is true.

If none of the statements are true, then all $100$ of them are false. However that would make the $100$th statement true, which is a contradiction.

Hence the only possibility is that exactly one statement is true and $99$ are false. If this is the case, the the $99$th statement is true and the remaining $99$ are indeed false.

Answer (score 0):

If $99$ statements are false, then the ninety ninth statement is true, but the other $99$ statements are false.